# What happened while using a hash as the parameter when initializing a instance in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I defined a class for User, which takes a hash as parameter, 
    class User
      attr_accessor :name, :email

```
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @name  = attributes[:name]
    @email = attributes[:email]
  end

  def formatted_email
    "#{@name} <#{@email}>"
  end
end
```

While initializing in console using parenthesis and empty space syntax for parameter, the behaviours are different, the second one didn't receive the attributes, but if I define a hash first and then initialize with the hash as the parameter, it works well now, why does this happen?

```
2.0.0-p451 :013 > example = User.new(name:'John', email:'john@example.com')
 => #<User:0x007fbcdb57e140 @name="John", @email="john@example.com"> 
2.0.0-p451 :014 > example = User.new {name:'John', email:'john@example.com'}
 => #<User:0x007fbcdb599080 @name=nil, @email=nil> 
2.0.0-p451 :021 > hash = {name: 'John', email: 'john@example.com'}
 => {:name=>"John", :email=>"john@example.com"} 
2.0.0-p451 :022 > User.new hash
 => #<User:0x007fbcdc4af8a8 @name="John", @email="john@example.com">
```

Answer (score 3):

Look the code :

```
class User 
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    p attributes # I put it to debug the hash **attributes** after each *new* call.
    @name  = attributes[:name]
    @email = attributes[:email]
  end

  def formatted_email
    "#{@name} <#{@email}>"
  end
end

# here you did pass the method argument as a Hash.
User.new(name:'John', email:'john@example.com') 
# >> {:name=>"John", :email=>"john@example.com"} # output of attributes hash
# you got #<User:0x007fbcdb57e140 @name="John", @email="john@example.com">, as the
# hash **attributes** is, {:name=>"John", :email=>"john@example.com"}. So inside the 
# initialize method
#  @name  = "John" as , attributes[:name] is "John"
#  @email = "john@example.com" as, attributes[:email] is "john@example.com"

# here you didn't pass the method argument as a Hash, rather a block.
User.new {name:'John', email:'john@example.com'}
# >> {} # output of attributes hash is empty hash.
# you got #<User:0x007fbcdb599080 @name=nil, @email=nil>, as *attributes* is empty.
# so inside the initialize method @name  = nil happened, as attributes[:name] is nil.
# @email = nil, as attributes[:email] is nil.

# here you did pass the method argument as a Hash.
hash = {name: 'John', email: 'john@example.com'}
User.new hash # output of attributes hash
# >> {:name=>"John", :email=>"john@example.com"}
```

In Ruby, the method calling syntax is

- `meth_name(argument_list_of_object/objects) { #block }`
- `meth_name(argument_list_of_object/objects)`
- `meth_name argument_list_of_object/objects`. This is valid when you are not passing block,otherwise error will be thorwn

It means in Ruby, `{ .. }` after method call, parsed as if, you are sending a block to the method, not as if you are passing the *hash* as argument.

One more simple example to illustrate this theory :

```
def foo(arg = 10)
  p arg
end

foo 12 # => 12
foo(12) # => 12
foo { 12 } # => 10 default value
foo "arg" { 12 }
# ~> -:8: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting end-of-input
# ~> foo "arg" { 12 }
# ~>
```

*Summarizing :*

```
# you are passing a 2 key/value argument, which in runtime will create a hash
# {name:'John', email:'john@example.com'}, then will be assigned to
# local variable attributes of the method initialize.
User.new name:'John', email:'john@example.com'
# => #<User:0x90f5a24 @email="john@example.com", @name="John">

# same as above
User.new(name:'John', email:'john@example.com')
# => #<User:0x90f4a5c @email="john@example.com", @name="John">

# simply passing a block to the method.
User.new {name:'John', email:'john@example.com'}
# => #<User:0x90f7450 @email=nil, @name=nil>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @sawa - When you have time, could you review this ? And also I would be happy very much, if you edit this answer with your skilled editing ability. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the empty space, following should print correct, I have removed white space and added parentheses

`example = User.new({name: 'John', email: 'john@example.com'})`